# URLDownloadToFile and Authentication

Tags: c++, authentication, download, ntlm, urlmon

I'm working on some old ATL OCX, that is used as "download manager".
It downloads files using **URLDownloadToFile** API.

Previously, it was hosted as ActiveX on web page so in case the server required authentication it was done by IE. Now it is part of executable, so it should take care of authentication.
Let say user provided username and password, how I can actually to do "authentication" ? I need support **Simple Web Authentication** and **NTLM** for IIS.

For **Simple Web Authentication** i found out that passing username/password before URL works fine. But I'm not sure that it is a proper way to so.

Please advise
Thank you
Zaky

Answer (score 3):

**Simple Web Authentication** can be done using `http://username:password@webaddress.com` and should be fine. It's a safe and simple way to do this.
**If for some reason you need more than this** you can re-implement this function by using `InternetOpen`, `InternetSetOption`, `InternetReadFile`. This should be fast and easy.